# makeValidWord(std::string word) not working properly

Tags: c++

I'm programming a hash table thing in C++, but this specific piece of code will not run properly. It should return a string of alpha characters and ' and -, but I get cases like "t" instead of "art" when I try to input "'aRT-*".

- isWordChar() return a bool value depending on whether the input is a valid word character or not using isAlpha()

```
 // Words cannot contain any digits, or special characters EXCEPT for
 // hyphens (-) and apostrophes (') that occur in the middle of a
 // valid word (the first and last characters of a word must be an alpha
 // character). All upper case characters in the word should be convertd
 // to lower case.
 // For example, "can't" and "good-hearted" are considered valid words.
 // "12mOnkEYs-$" will be converted to "monkeys".
 // "Pa55ive" will be stripped "paive".

std::string WordCount::makeValidWord(std::string word) {
    if (word.size() == 0) {
        return word;
    }
    string r = "";
    string in = "";
    size_t incr = 0;
    size_t decr = word.size() - 1;
    while (incr < word.size() && !isWordChar(word.at(incr))) {
        incr++;
    }
    while (0 < decr && !isWordChar(word.at(decr))) {
        decr--;
    }
    if (incr > decr) {
        return r;
    }
    while (incr <= decr) {
        if (isWordChar(word.at(incr)) || word.at(incr) == '-' || word.at(incr) == '\'') {
            in =+ word.at(incr);
        }
        incr++;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < in.size(); i++) {
        r += tolower(in.at(i));
    }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: Unless it's an assignment requirement that you do this yourself, then use [`std::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) to remove unwanted characters, and [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) together with [`std::tolower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower) to convert to lower-case.

Comment: As for your current code, I suggest you learn how to use a *debugger* to step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. That way you can easily see when things go wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you can use standard algorithms its better to rewrite your function using them. This achieves 2 goals:

- code is more readable, since using algorithms shows intent along with code itself
- there is less chance to make error

So it should be something like this:

```
std::string WordCount::makeValidWord(std::string word) {
    auto first = std::find_if(word.cbegin(), word.cend(), isWordChar);
    auto last = std::find_if(word.crbegin(), word.crend(), isWordChar);
    std::string i;
    std::copy_if(first, std::next(last), std::back_inserter(i), [](char c) {
        return isWordChar(c) || c == '-' || c == '\'';
    });
    std::string r;
    std::transform(i.cbegin(), i.cend(), std::back_inserter(r), std::tolower);
    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to echo @Someprogrammerdude and say: Learn to use a debugger!

I pasted your code into Visual Studio (changed `isWordChar()` to `isalpha()`), and stepped it through with the debugger. Then it was pretty trivial to notice this happening:

First loop of `while (incr <= decr) {`:
[image]

Second loop:
[image]

Ooh, look at that; the variable `in` does not update correctly - instead of collecting a string of the correct characters it only holds the last one. How can that be?

`in =+ word.at(incr);` Hey, that is not right, that operator should be `+=`.

Many errors are that easy and effortless to find and correct if you use a debugger. Pick one up today. :)

Comment: Passive aggressive much?

Comment: @const_ref Passive aggressive? No, I was trying for "overly enthusiastic salesman"...